# Deploying a Django App to App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, gunicorn, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to deploy a [sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql) to the Google App Engine Flexible Environment based on [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment) tutorial. The deployment works, however, the application cannot start up. I get the following error message:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [5] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [5] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (5)
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [5] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'mysite'
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [5] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-01-21 17:01:14 +0000] [5] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

As you can see on GitHub (see link above), the **/app.yaml** file looks like this:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: <your-cloudsql-connection-string>

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
# [END runtime]
```

And the **/mysite/wsgi.py** file like this:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Since the Flexible Environment is in beta, I am not sure if this might be a bug. However, I am using the original app from GitHub without any changes following the official documentation, so I would expect it to work.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from Adam (Google Cloud Platform team member on the [Google Group Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/ntL6QAHy2A8)) that the files are probably not getting deployed, I updated the Google Cloud SDK from 138.0.0 to 141.0.0. Now everything works fine as described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi:application`

(assuming the directory "mysite" is at the same level as `app.yaml`.  If `wsgi.py` is at the same level as `app.yaml`, then just: `:$PORT wsgi:application`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get the same error. I think _application_ is the default parameter, so it should work without, just like in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/). You can see the directory structure on [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your requirements have been met, i.e. copy requirements.txt to the root of your project

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/django_cloudsql/requirements.txt

which looks like this

```
Django==1.11.1
mysqlclient==1.3.10
wheel==0.29.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
psycopg2==2.7.1
```

and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then gcloud app deploy